# POI and XMLBeans confilict

Tags: java, apache-poi, websphere-8, xmlbeans

I use POI to deal with excel files and it works file on my local machine but when deploying my app into websphere i got this exception `Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: XML-BEANS compiled schema: Incompatible minor version - expecting up to 23, got 24 (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sF1327CCA741569E70F9CA8C9AF9B44B2.index) - code 3`  after some search i figure out the root cause of the exception is  conflict of xmlBeans jars the jars i used are included into the ear file.i don't know what exactly made the conflict?

Comment: It's not only the case of adding the new jars to your deployment, you also need to remove the older jars! There is a code snippet at http://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html for detecting what jar you are using for Apache POI, modify that for a XMLBeans class to check for that

Comment: @Gagravarr how to find the older jars to remove? and how to detecting what jar i am  using for Apache POI? i cann't got it from the link ?

Comment: `ClassLoader classloader = org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.class.getClassLoader(); java.net.URL res = classloader.getResource("org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlBeans.class"‌​); String path = res.getPath(); System.out.println("XmlBeans came from " + path);`

Comment: Is there any other way to  list the jars without coding? because  it would be hard to maintain the exciting ear code?

Comment: ear files are zip files - try using a zip tool to unzip the ear file and see what copies of the xmlbeans jar that you have - the xmlbeans jar is itself a zip file but the xmlbeans jar file name might have the version number in it already